# android - How to get data from a card view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to get Data from a `CardView`.

```
myData.add(new Archivos("Tittle", "Description", 0));
```

I have 3 parameters,

1. Tittle
2. Description
3. and Type which I would like not to show, I just want to know later which type it is and what to do then.

This is how I set the values into the card view:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset.get(position).titulo);
    holder.mTextView2.setText(mDataset.get(position).descripcion);
}
```

But I'm not sure, how to get the data once is displayed.

How can I get the value of type on my `Adapter`?

Comment: You _have_ the data.  It is contained in `mDataset`.

Comment: Thanks actually it was pretty easy, i just call the getText() method into my MyViewHolder class and that's it.

now the things is, how can i set a variable into my card, i mean, i dont want to have it into my XML. How can i get it?

Comment: If you simply want to get the object out of your dataset that corresponds with the position of the view, you can get the view position, say when onClick happens, out of the adapter, and then pull the object out of your dataset using that position.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data as part of ViewHolder and get the data from the ViewHolder. To get ViewHolder for a view, you can call getTag() method on that view.

Here's a sample:

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private MyData myData;
    // more fields here

    MyViewHolder(MyData myData) {
        this.myData = myData;
        // more assignments here
    }

    public MyData getMyData() {
        return myData;
    }
}

View view = layoutManager.findViewByPosition(whateverPositionYouWant);
if (view != null) {
    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();
    MyData data = myViewHolder.getMyData();
}
```